# Send an email alert from an email

Tags: email, workflow, process-builder, email-alert

Is it possible, using Process Builder, to send an email alert when an email is created?
Scenario: If I send out a quotation email I want a follow up email to go out the following day.

My solution is to create a task with specific criteria and then create an email if a task is created with that matching criteria.

In more detail:

1. When an email message is created, if the subject line = "Quotation" then create a Task with the subject = QuotationSent.
2. When Task is created, if the Subject = QuotationSent then activate an email alert "send follow up email"

However I get an error message when I activate both processes and create an email and send it "Workflow Action failed to Trigger"

I have been able to successfully create a task with the QuotationSent subject line and get an email confirmation proving that the second process works. If I deactivate the second process i can get an email with quotation attachment, proving that the first process works. 
For some reason, the two processes won't work together.

Comment: May be you can add two actions, one as as Immediate Action and second as a  Scheduled Action which will be same as Time Based Action.

Comment: thanks, can't add a scheduled action (using the email object). Looks like I need to create a task and then a new process that sends an email alert based on the new task created

Comment: The EmailMessage object is available when you select Object while creating a Process using Process Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Enable enhance email in your org. Then you can monitor Email Message Object just like an object can do anything write trigger, Process Builder to do what ever you want